# how to loop through workbooks in folder , check values in a row and if criteria met close else remain open

Tags: excel, vba

i have a folder with over 100 workbooks (all with the same structure) with only one sheet in it  . I need a macro to open the workbook and check a hole row(9th row) if a value exist in the cells (30 columns). if this value exist , need to check the value to the below cell (10th row). if criteria met the workbook closes , else remains open for corrections

I'm new to vba so help need
my code doesn't work

```
Sub scannerblaine()

Dim SPath As String 'path to check
Dim sFname As String 'the name of the workbooks for scaning (if all scaned = * )
Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim wSht As Variant 'the name of the sheets to be scaned
Dim r1, r2 As Integer 'this is the rows for scanning
Dim c1 As Integer 'columns for scanning
Dim blaine, varblaine, b1, b2 As Double

Dim res As Integer
res = MsgBox(" SCANNING OF MT FOLDER" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "CHOOSE FOLDER" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "NAME OF THE EXCEL FILES" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "IF ALL THE SAME PLACE {*} " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "", vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2, " INFO !!!")
If res = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Please select a folder for scanning"
    .Show
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .SelectedItems.count = 0 Then 'if no folder is selected , abort
    MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
Exit Sub
End If

SPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'assign selected folder to be the scanned folder
End With
ChDir SPath
sFname = InputBox("Enter a filename pattern")
sFname = Dir(SPath & "\" & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal)

' INPUT BOX FOR blaine ###################################################################################################
    blaine = Application.InputBox("TARGET BLAINE", Type:=1)
 varblaine = Application.InputBox("BLAINE VARIATION", Type:=1)
 b1 = blaine - varblaine
 b2 = blaine + varblaine
 Dim resl As Integer
 resl = MsgBox(b1 & " to " & b2, vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2)
 If resl = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

ChDir SPath
    Filename = Dir(SPath & "\" & "*.xl*")
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=SPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename)

    For c1 = 6 To 36    '0 '########################################################################################
    r1 = 9
        If Cells(r1, c1) = "I52,5N" Then
        If Cells(r1 + 1, c1) < b2 And Cells(r1 + 1, c1) > b1 Then
        wBk.Close
        End If
        End If
    Next c1

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Filename = Dir()
Loop

MsgBox _
"SCAN IN FOLDER" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& SPath & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& " COMPLETE"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that *"doesn't work"* is a completely useless error description. We need to know what is wrong with that code. You cannot throw in your whole code and ask us to fix it. We can just help you to solve your issue yourself but we cannot do the work for you. So we need either to know where you got errors and which or what your code actually does vs what you expect it to do. Also we need a good [mcve].

Comment: Note that if you `Dim r1, r2 As Integer` only `r2` is `Integer` but `r1` is `Variant`. In VBA you must specify a type for **every** variable otherwise it is `Variant` by default. Also row counting variables need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long`. Fix all your variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Sub scannerblaine()

```
Dim SPath As String 'path to check
Dim sFname As String 'the name of the workbooks for scaning (if all scaned = * )
Dim wBk As Object
Dim wSht As Variant 'the name of the sheets to be scaned
Dim r1, r2 As Integer 'this is the rows for scanning
Dim c1, c2 As Variant 'columns for scanning
Dim blaine, varblaine, b1, b2 As Integer

Dim res As Integer
res = MsgBox(" ΘΑ ΣΑΡΩΘΕΙ ΕΝΑΣ ΦΑΚΕΛΟΣ ΤΟΥ ΑΡΧΕΙΟΥ MT" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "ΕΠΕΛΕΞΕ ΠΟΙΟΣ ΑΠΟ ΤΟ ΠΑΡΑΘΥΡΟ ΔΙΑΛΟΓΟΥ" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "ΚΑΤΟΠΙΝ ΘΑ ΣΟΥ ΖΗΤΗΘΕΙ ΤΟ ΟΝΟΜΑ ΤΩΝ EXCEL ΑΡΧΕΙΩΝ" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "ΕΠΕΙΔΗ ΕΙΝΑΙ ΤΑ ΙΔΙΑ ΑΠΛΑ ΒΑΛΕ [ * ] [αστερισκος] " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "", vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2, " ΕΝΗΜΕΡΩΣΗ !!!")
If res = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Please select a folder for scanning"
    .Show
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .SelectedItems.count = 0 Then 'if no folder is selected , abort
    MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
Exit Sub
End If

SPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'assign selected folder to be the scanned folder
End With
ChDir SPath
sFname = InputBox("Enter a filename pattern")
sFname = Dir(SPath & "\" & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal)

'Να φτιαξω input box για την ποιοτητα I42,5R ή I52,5N και να συμπεριλαβω την ποιοτητα στο input box του blaine παρακατω

' INPUT BOX FOR blaine ###################################################################################################
    blaine = Application.InputBox("ΔΩΣΕ ΣΤΟΧΟ BLAINE", Type:=1)
 varblaine = Application.InputBox("ΔΩΣΕ ΕΥΡΟΣ ΔΙΑΚΥΚΑΝΣHΣ BLAINE", Type:=1)
 b1 = blaine - varblaine
 b2 = blaine + varblaine
 Dim resl As Integer
 resl = MsgBox("ΟΡΙΑ BLAINE ΑΠΟ " & b1 & " ΕΩΣ " & b2, vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2)
 If resl = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

ChDir SPath
    Filename = Dir(SPath & "\" & "*.xl*")
    Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=SPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename)

'CHECK FOR BLAINE VALUES IN CELLS ##########################################################################################

   For c1 = 6 To 30
   r1 = 9
   If Cells(r1, c1) = "I52,5N" Then
   If Cells(r1 + 2, c1) > b2 Or Cells(r1 + 2, c1) < b1 Then GoTo c
   End If
   Next c1
   wBk.Close
```

c:
    Filename = Dir()
    Loop

```
MsgBox _
"Η ΣΑΡΩΣΗ ΣΤΟΝ ΦΑΚΕΛΟ" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& SPath & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "ΟΛΟΚΛΗΡΩΘΗΚΕ" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "ΤΑ ΑΡΧΕΙΑ ΜΕ ΣΦΑΛΜΑΤΑ" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
& "ΠΑΡΑΜΕΝΟΥΝ ΑΝΟΙΧΤΑ ΓΙΑ ΕΠΕΞΕΡΓΑΣΙΑ"

End Sub
```

Comment: solved
this code scans through multiple excel workbooks in a folder for a string "I52,5N" in cells r1 , c1
(dismiss the greeks in msgboxes)
If founds it , checks the value (blaine) in cell r1+2 , c1 if meets the criteria given in inputbox for blaine